# Finding the right codec for AVI (ffmpeg C api implementation)

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to implement AVI encoding into some software that we've been creating. We've been using ffmpeg for WMV (we've done it pretty badly and hacked together as we're not experts in C or ffmpeg but got it to work).

I'm trying to find the right Codec ID for AVI and I've come up with H.263 which I believe to be correct but there doesn't seem to be much information on it around, or I'm asking the wrong questions.

I'm not a much of a audio/video expert but I know enough to (hopefully) get this working for AVI, I was wondering if anyone had any idea as to what the (or a) codec is for encoding an AVI media file.

Been fumbling our way through it for a while but now we want to support a new file type for various reasons and this has now been handed over to me. Hopefully it can be done!

Comment: avi is very versatile and has been hacked over the years to support almost any codec. It sounds like you need to do more research. When the client (user of your software) plays avi files, what codec do those have? Can examine files using the commandline tool ffprobe. Then can use the same codec for your software's output.

Comment: @njahnke That sounds like a good direction to head in thanks. Yeah I've been set the task of doing this and I've no real idea which way I'm heading. With the documentation ffmpeg provides it's proving pretty damn tough to get the results I'm after.

Comment: This question confuses me so I'm hoping to get a bit more clarification about what you're trying to do. Are you trying to write software to generate new AVI files? If so, what video codec do you want to use inside of these files? Are you creating a new codec? Or will you use an established codec?

Comment: @MultimediaMike The problems actually been solved now, somewhat thanks to njahnke. When I asked the question I wasn't really sure what was going on. I was looking to find out what video codec I could use with an avi container for muxing. I've done a lot more reading and experimenting now and found how to mux using ffmpeg for an API.

Thanks :)